# Display Message on webview for specific duration in Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am new to Android devp. I am using webview for webpage showing Now I want to display certain message during specific duration in webview. Like I want to show "Shop is closed" from 5pm to 5am in webview. kindly tell me how to do this

Comment: make that content in web page with your time constrains and show it android webview

Comment: Well I showed the message in webview but I want it to show the message at the top of my desired url. I didnt get about time constraints. Is there any class or method regarding this

Comment: ```I want it to show the message at the top of my desired url``` in activity bar?

Comment: I am sorry I dont know how to say this technically. When I opened the URL ... i want to insert that message on the top row of that page.